# format en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy buscando una opción que me permita generar un listado de empleados y salarios, dado que empleados al ser de tipo string se deben llenar con espacios a la derecha (máximo 15 caracteres), y salarios al ser de tipo entero colocar 0 (máximo 10 decimales) a la izquierda.

En el momento tengo un código sencillo. Lo muestro a continuación:

```
empleados = ['Juan Carlos Mayorga Perez','Marjorie Zambrano Zapata', 'Benjamín Otalora Lopez']

salarios = [1000,2000,3000]

for empleado in empleados:
    for salario in salarios:
        print("{:<15}{:010d}".format(empleado,salario))
```

Lo que deseo hacer es que quede alineado y si un nombre tiene más de 15 caracteres lo corte y escriba lo que alcance en esa longitud y continue con el salario de cada empleado, pero no me funciona (siempre me muestra todo el nombre).

Espero haberme explicado bien y agradezco cualquier ayuda que me puedan brindar

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar cómo debería verse el resultado?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Si te he entendido bien, es esto lo que buscas:

```
for empleado in empleados:
    for salario in salarios:
        print(f"{empleado[:15]:<15} {salario}")
```

Con `[:15]` le dices que tome el string desde la posición 0 hasta la 15, con `:<15` rellena hasta completar los 15 caracteres en caso de que la cadena sea más corta.

La parte de poner máximo 10 decimales en el salario no la he entendido muy bien, ya que dices que los datos son de tipo entero. Si lo que quieres es poner ceros a la izquierda para que todos tengan 10 números, puedes cambiar `{salario}` por `{salario:010d}`

Por último, cuando vas a trabajar con grupos de listas que tienen relación entre sus índices, puedes unirlas en tuplas utilizando zip():

```
for e, s in zip(empleados, salarios):
    print(f"{e[:15]:<15} {s:010d}")
```

Para que entiendas lo que hace zip:

```
x = ['a', 'b', 'c']
y = [1, 2, 3]

print(list(zip(x, y)))  # esto imprimiría [('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)]
```

Comment: `e[:15]` limita la salida a 15 caracteres si la cadena `e` tenía más, pero no rellena hasta ocupar 15 si tenía menos. El usuario quería ambas cosas.

Comment: Ya lo he modificado para que se entienda mejor, había entendido que el :<15 lo había puesto en su intento de truncar la cadena. Muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 3):

Casi lo tenías. El formato `"{:<15}"` es para rellenar si tiene menos de 15, pero nunca para recortar si tiene más.

Pero el recorte puedes hacerlo antes de pasarlo a `format()`, por ejemplo así: `empleado[:15]`. Es decir:

```
empleados = ['Juan Carlos Mayorga Perez','Marjorie Zambrano Zapata', 'Benjamín Otalora Lopez']

salarios = [1000,2000,3000]

for empleado, salario in zip(empleados, salarios):
    print("{:<15} {:010d}".format(empleado[:15], salario))
```

```
Juan Carlos May 0000001000
Marjorie Zambra 0000002000
Benjamín Otalor 0000003000
```

Si quieres algo más sofisticado, como por ejemplo que añada puntos suspensivos si se ha cortado, puedes programar una función que lo haga, y llamarla desde el `format()`. O hacer uso de `textwrap.shorten()` que ya viene en Python. El inconviente de ésta (o su ventaja, depende de lo que quieras) es que nunca te romperá "a mitad" de una palabra, sino sólo en los espacios.

Ejemplo:

```
from textwrap import shorten

empleados = ['Juan Carlos Mayorga Perez','Marjorie Zambrano Zapata', 'Benjamín Otalora Lopez']

salarios = [1000,2000,3000]

for empleado, salario in zip(empleados, salarios):
    print("{:<15} {:010d}".format(shorten(empleado, 15, placeholder="..."), salario))
```

```
Juan Carlos...  0000001000
Marjorie...     0000002000
Benjamín...     0000003000
```

Si prefieres que el corte se produzca aún en mitad del nombre, puedes programar tu propia función `shorten()` como la siguiente:

```py
def shorten(nombre, tam=15):
  if len(nombre) <=tam:
    return nombre
  return nombre[:tam-3] + "..."

empleados = ['Juan Carlos Mayorga Perez','Marjorie Zambrano Zapata', 'Benjamín Otalora Lopez', "Don Pepe"]

salarios = [1000,2000,3000, 5000]

for empleado, salario in zip(empleados, salarios):
    print("{:<15} {:010d}".format(shorten(empleado), salario))
```

```
Juan Carlos ... 0000001000
Marjorie Zam... 0000002000
Benjamín Ota... 0000003000
Don Pepe        0000005000
```

O puedes hacer una que reemplace por puntos suspensivos la parte central del nombre, permitiéndote leer cómo empieza y cómo termina. En algunos escenarios esto puede ser más útil (sobre todo en nombres de ficheros). Por ejemplo así:

```py
def shorten(nombre, tam=15):
  if len(nombre) <=tam:
    return nombre
  return nombre[:(tam-3)//2] + "..." + nombre[-(tam-3)//2:]
```

que produciría:

```
Juan C... Perez 0000001000
Marjor...Zapata 0000002000
Benjam... Lopez 0000003000
Don Pepe        0000005000
```